# /usr/sbin/thin_check: execvp failed: No such file or directory

Tags: centos6, lvm

Running CentOS 6.5, a brand new "minimal" server install, trying to use LVM2 thin pool feature.  Packages installed are:

lvm2 (2.02.111)
device-mapper-persistent-data-0.3.2-1.el6.x86_64

/etc/lvm/lvm.conf has

```
...
thin_check_executable = "/usr/sbin/thin_check"
thin_repair_executable = "/usr/sbin/thin_repair"
...
```

(And yes those files exist in the file system.)

Error message in /var/log/boot.log is:

```
Setting up Logical Volume Management:   /usr/sbin/thin_check: execvp failed: No such file or directory
Check of pool vg/pool failed (status:2). Manual repair required!
/usr/sbin/thin_check: execvp failed: No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/thin_check: execvp failed: No such file or directory
```

I'm at a loss of what to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using centos 7 and i don't have this problem, the function execvp is an external functions resolved by the library `libdevmapper-event-lvm2thin.so`:

```
/usr/lib64/device-mapper/libdevmapper-event-lvm2thin.so
[root@localhost ~]# objdump -T /usr/lib64/device-mapper/libdevmapper-event-lvm2thin.so  | grep exec
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 execvp
[root@localhost ~]# grep thin /etc/lvm/lvm.conf | grep -v "#"
    thin_pool_metadata_require_separate_pvs = 0
    thin_pool_autoextend_threshold = 100
    thin_pool_autoextend_percent = 20
    thin_library = "libdevmapper-event-lvm2thin.so"


[root@localhost ~]# locate libdevmapper-event-lvm2thin.so
/usr/lib64/libdevmapper-event-lvm2thin.so
/usr/lib64/device-mapper/libdevmapper-event-lvm2thin.so

rpm -qf /usr/lib64/device-mapper/libdevmapper-event-lvm2thin.so
lvm2-libs-2.02.105-14.el7.x86_64
```

I think you need to say to lvm what library to use

Comment: On CentOS 6, the /lib64/ .so file is just a link to the one under the /lib64/device-mapper/ directory.

Comment: yes, i know, but have you try to set in lvm.conf to that library?

Comment: No luck yet, even with hard-coding the path of the library into the config file.

Comment: ldconfig -p | grep event ?